# How to solve Heap dump out of memory error in cassendra in windows azure instance?

Tags: ubuntu, azure, cassandra

Deployed Cassandra in windows azure instance using juju. While checking the juju status Cassandra is running properly. While trying to instantiate the Cassandra (./usr/sbin/cassandra
) the followinf error is showing

```
xss =  -ea -javaagent:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jamm-0.2.5.jar -XX:+UseThreadPriorities -XX:ThreadPriorityPolicy=42 -Xms840M -Xmx840M -Xmn100M -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xss180k
```

How to solve the Out of memory problem in windows azure ?

Answer (score 0):

First the line you are listing is not an error, but looks like a line of JVM settings. It sets the JVM to start with allocating 840 megabytes of ram, with a max of 840 mb and min 100 mb.

I would suggestig starting to increase those values.

This also depends very much on what data you are loading and the load in general - clustersize etc. Take a look at datastax docs for an Amazon deployment, they might be transferable to Azure..

Good luck